# Showing H is a normal subgroup of G if $\vert H \vert = \frac{\vert G \vert }{2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

> Show that if $G$ is a finite group of order $n$, and $H$ is a subgroup of order $\frac{n}{2}$, then $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Please help me on this. I only know that $|gH| = |H|$. How can go on beyond that to attempt the problem?

Comment: You can check this [link](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_of_Index_2_is_Normal) to solve this problem

Comment: There is a nice generalization of this question: if p is the smallest prime numer dividing the order of the group, then any subgroup of index p is normal.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:** What are the left cosets of $H$ in $G$? What are the right cosets of $H$ in $G$? Finally, note that if $g \in G$ but $g \notin H$, then $gH \neq H$ and $Hg \neq H$.

Comment: :To me  the problem seems to be more general,please give me more direction.

Comment: What do you mean 'the problem seems to be more general'? Can you answer the questions I posed?

Comment: @nzobo: No more detailed information is needed here. Just reflect the directions in the post. +1

Comment: @nzobo: The main point is there are only two left or right cosets $H$ and $gH$ for any $g\in G\H$. Actually $gH=G\H$ for any $g\in G\H$

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to prove $H\unlhd G $ i.e.,

> $gH=Hg$ for all $g\in G$

Take some $g\in G$...

If your choice is from $H$ you have nothing to prove (??)

If your choice is not from $H$ then you can not immediately  say $gH=Hg$

By $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ of order $\frac{n}{2}$ you actually mean there are only two cosets of $H$ in $G$..

Now Any two cosets are either equal or disjoint.. Why???

If $g\notin H$ then...

Can $H=gH$??

Can $H=Hg$??

If there are only two cosets...

how do you see containment of $G$ and $ H\cup gH$

how do you see containment of $G$ and $ H\cup Hg$